# Problema al buscar un elemento concreto de una matriz

Tags: array, c

Estoy recorriendo una matriz de enteros que debe encontrar un elemento concreto (un punto de silla, aquel que sea el menor de su fila y el mayor de su columna).

El programa funciona bien si utilizo un bucle for para recorrer la matriz que emite un mensaje para cada posición. Mi problema es que quiero que solo escriba un mensaje: si ha encontrado punto de silla o si no ha encontrado ninguno.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 3
#define N 4

void leeMat(int mat[M][N]);
int puntoSilla(int mat[M][N], int posFila, int posColumna);
void escribeMat(int mat[M][N]);

void main()
{
    int mat[M][N]=
    {
        1, 4, 0, 3,
        1, 3, 0, 7,
        3, 3, 2, 3,  //punto de silla en posicion 2-2
    }, posFila, posColumna, existe=1;

    printf("\n");
    escribeMat(mat);

    for(posFila=0; posFila<M && existe; posFila++)
    {
        for(posColumna=0; posColumna<N && existe; posColumna++)
        {
            if(puntoSilla(mat, posFila, posColumna)!=1)
                existe=0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    if(existe)
     printf("Tiene punto de silla en la posicion %d-%d\n", posFila, posColumna);

    else printf("No tiene punto de silla\n");
}

void leeMat(int mat[M][N])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("Escribe valor para la posicion %d-%d: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int puntoSilla(int mat[M][N], int posFila, int posColumna)
{
    int i, j, enc=1;

    for(j=0; j<N && enc; j++)
    {
        if(mat[posFila][posColumna]>mat[posFila][j])
            enc=0;
    }

    if(enc)
    {
        for(i=0; i<M && enc; i++)
        {
            if(mat[posFila][posColumna]<mat[i][posColumna])
                enc=0;
        }
    }

    else enc=0;

    return enc;
}

void escribeMat(int mat[M][N])
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Lo que estoy explicando se encuentra en la función principal. Si alguien supiera cuál es el problema estaría muy agradecido. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra en que esás asumiendo que tienes un punto de silla y te dedicas a iterar por la matriz hasta que encuentras un punto que no cumple el requisito y debería ser al revés:

```
int existe=0;

for(posFila=0; posFila<M && !existe; posFila++)
{
    for(posColumna=0; posColumna<N && !existe; posColumna++)
    {
        existe = puntoSilla(mat, posFila, posColumna);
    }
}
```

¿Por qué? Básicamente porque antes de iterar no has encontrado el punto de silla, luego `existe=1` es una gran mentira. El hecho de que `puntoSilla` devuelva 0 si el punto actual no es el buscado hace que en la primera iteración `existe` pase a valer 0, lo que hace que el algoritmo no siga buscando... solo te salvarías si el punto de silla se encuentra en la primera celda.

Este tipo de errores los encontrarías rápidamente si aprendieses a utilizar un depurador de código. Son una herramienta imprescindible para programar así que te recomiendo que te des prisa en aprender a usarlos.

Por otro lado, si me permites la crítica, intenta evitar código redundante. Me explico. En este código, por ejemplo:

```
if(enc)
{
  for(i=0; i<M && enc; i++)
  {
    if(mat[posFila][posColumna]<mat[i][posColumna])
      enc=0;
  }
}
else enc=0;
```

Podemos eliminar ambos condicionales. El exterior sobra porque el propio `for` tiene como condicional que `enc` tenga un valor diferente de 0 y no olvidemos que el condicional de un `for` se ejecuta para cada iteración, la primera incluída. Además, el `else` es igualmente redundante ya que en tu función `enc` únicamente puede valer 1 o 0, luego si no vale 1 está claro que va a valer 0.

Para eliminar el segundo condicional hay que entender que en C una condición devuelve 1 o 0 en función de si la misma es verdadera o falsa. Si la intención es que `enc` valga 0 si se encuentra un valor más alto basta con encontrar una condición que sea falsa únicamente en ese caso.

El equivalente simplificado quedaría así:

```
for(i=0; i<M && enc; i++)
{
  enc = (mat[posFila][posColumna]>=mat[i][posColumna]);
}
```

E incluso podríamos evitar declarar las variables al principio de la función y tenerlas dentro del bucle. De esta forma la variable deja de existir al finalizar el bucle. No conviene tener variables vivas una vez han cumplido su misión:

```
for(int i=0; i<M && enc; i++)
{
  enc = (mat[posFila][posColumna]>=mat[i][posColumna]);
}
```

Un saludo.